# Comapring dictionary with list type values

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following 2 dictionaries,

```
d1={"aa":[1,2,3],"bb":[4,5,6],"cc":[7,8,9]}
d2={"aa":[1,2,3],"bb":[1,1,1,1,1,1],"cc":[7,8]}
```

How could I compare these two dictionaries and get the
positions(indexes) of UNMATCHED key value pairs? since I am dealing
with files of size around 2 GB, the dictionaries contain very large
data. How can this be implemented in optimized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getUniqueEntry(dictionary1, dictionary2, listOfKeys):
    assert sorted(dictionary1.keys()) == sorted(dictionary2.keys()), "Keys don't match"  #check that they have the same keys
    for key in dictionary1:
        if dictionary1[key] != dictionary2[key]:
            listOfKeys.append(key)
```

When calling the function, the third param `listOfKeys` is an empty list where you want the keys to be stored. Note that reading 2 gb worth of data into a dict requires alot of ram and will most likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

and this is a more pythonic way: The list expansion will consider just the values that are not equal in both dictionaries:

```
diffrent_keys = [key for key in d1 if d1[key] != d2[key] ]
```